# Как реализовать многоуровневое меню больше двух уровней

Tags: jquery, меню, списки, ul

Делаю меню. Подскажите как реализовать меню с тремя или четырьмя уровнями чтобы при нажатии на пункт открывался следующий блок а другие пункты закрывались. Получилось реализовать только один блок подпунктов. А как сделать больше?!

```
<div id="menu">
       <div class="sub-one">
            <ul class=" scroll-pane">

                <li><a href="#">Backgrounds</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Graphics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HTML & CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PSD</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Templates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>


            </ul>
       </div>


        <div class="sub-two">
            <ul class="scroll-pane">
                <li><a href="#">About PSDGraphics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Commercial Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms Of Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms Of Use</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="sub-two">
            <ul class="scroll-pane">
                <li><a href="#">1About PSDGraphics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2Commercial Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3Terms Of Use</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

$('.sub-one li').click(function () {

        $('.sub-two').eq($(this).index()).toggle().siblings('.sub-two').hide();
    });


.scroll-pane {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.sub-two {
    display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Tomak/vjj068fp/

Comment: достаточно просто набрать в гугле jquery menu http://jqueryui.com/menu/ и дальше по списку http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/article_2149.html и так далее

Comment: Спасибо. Но я ищу на подобии того, что я показал в коде. Тоесть без подпунктов.

Comment: вот тут что то подобное ? , http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/compactmenu.htm#  , можно отредактировать по идее ...